# programmatically localize info.plist on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am facing a problem with a specific translation issue on iOS.
The app I am currently working on gets all the texts it displays from a web service. I have been able to implement this everywhere with one single exception:

I have not yet found a way to programmatically alter texts from info.plist which get used from the system in code I cannot control. The one I need to deal with is "Privacy - Camera Usage Description". So far any documentation I have found tells me to add localized text versions for info.plist - but in this particular case this won't help me, because different customers may specify different texts for the same language, and I sometimes do not even know what language the texts are in, so I cannot solely rely on static data in the app to select the proper text version.

Is there any way to set such a text programmatically, or if that isn't possible to catch the alert displaying it and replace it with one of my own?

Comment: info.plist is localizable just like InfoPlist.strings and Localizable.strings.  If that's not going to help, then you have no other choice.  And there is no point of further discussion.

Comment: @ChristophO Those strings are requests for permissions, so they are sensitive and are reviewed by Apple before you publish your app. For security, there is no way that you can alter them without re-uploading a new build to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not possible, we can not change Info.plist runtime. But if I was there in place of you I will do one thing as a solution. **Display** a custom alertview with your specified text from the api. Which will ask that "We will use your camera". If user says "Ok" than display the system's alertview for the permission with static localized string. It needs 2 time interaction but it can guide user thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess that's what I'll suggest to the customer. I find it odd that it was never even considered that these texts may not be determinable at compile time. It has been common procedure for the things I work on that the customer gets a web interface where they can enter custom versions of texts they want to be different from the static defaults, which then get sent to the app on login, but I found it exceedingly complicated to make this work on iOS because it is all geared towards statically provided translations.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize `info.plist` file itself.
from project, go to your `info.plist` file and open Utilities tab and hit on Localization.
For different Localizations, use different Strings on specified keys.

#### Note

I Haven't tried it myself, just checked to see if it can be localized. and one more thing, using this way, Application will use Device's Localization (You can't use libraries to swizzle String table your app uses)

Comment: I surely know about this but it does not help my actual situation where I cannot specify the texts at compile time. Like I said, I get all texts from a web service. There can be different texts for the same item, depending on the customer's configuration.

Comment: Ow, in that case you have to do as others suggested. Cause it's implemented in coreOS level, and you can't access it no matter what(unless using privateAPI), you can put empty string in it and just pop up another alert or specific page for that alert (just like what facebook does). Apple will not reject this method, Apple just emphasized on the fact that user knows for what purpose he's giving permission, If you present a page or alert beforehand describing why you want this permission, they're ok with it.